# C++ program ( print out n words in alphabetical order ) runtime error

Tags: c++, c++11

I recently started to learn C++ programing, and watched many of your posts and answers with interest when my mind would lack the creativity. I have a few issues with this code right here. Basically it should show "n" words in alphabetical order. "n" being introduce by the user and the words as well. I get a weird error, could someone give me a few hints on what should i do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main () {
    int n=0;
    std::string cuvant;
    std::vector<std::string> lista_cuvinte;
    std::cout<<" Cate cuvinte doriti sa comparati = "<< std::endl;
    std::cin>> n;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"cubantul al " << i + 1 <<" -lea = ";
        std::cin>> cuvant;
        lista_cuvinte.push_back(cuvant);

        for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j=i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (lista_cuvinte.at(i) > lista_cuvinte.at(j))
                {
                    std::string temp=lista_cuvinte.at(i);
                    lista_cuvinte[i]=lista_cuvinte.at(j);
                    lista_cuvinte[j]=temp;
                    i=i-1;
                    break;
                    std::cout<< temp << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what on earth is this for `std: : string cuvant;`? Why all the extra space in the scope instead of `std::string`?

Comment: `std::sort` may help.

Comment: @Cyber Cuz "for (int i=0; \n i < n; \n i++)" =). My question, why not [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) ? There is also a `std::swap` for swapping, it should be faster than your way, because std::string has specialized and optimized swapping.

Comment: I honestly do not know, it must of edited that way when i copied it. In my compiler it's written std::string cuvant; . Thanks for the notice.

Comment: `I get a weird error`  What is this "weird error"?  Also, why not just use `std::sort()`?

Comment: @ShoRu - See an example here of `std::sort`: http://ideone.com/A2qh0m

Comment: Like i said i am new to this, please treat me like a noob :) the error goes something like this "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what<>: vector:_M_range_check"

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you. I was about to say i do not know how or where to implement this std::sort

Comment: @ShoRu You are not supposed to implement it. You are supposed to use it =)

Comment: This is more a question for codereview board.

Comment: @luk32 like i said i am new to this and my goal is to learn not to be making fun of. i would appreciate if you would laugh at my expense only for yourself and not here. thank you and a good day.

Comment: @ShoRu Whoa, what the heck. It was a sincere smile. I didn't write lmao, or rotfl, even a lol. If you look closer, my previous comment had a handy link to the documentation with an example. If you think about it, each comment contains an advice. Good day.

Comment: @luk32 you are right, I sincerely apologize and thank you for the learned lesson. I usually have a good sense of humour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot things wrong. Simply sorting starts before all data was read in in your code. Code after a break will never executed. And there is no output.

But you can achieve the same result much simpler by using `sort` from `algorithm`. I believe your code is only for learning, so it maybe makes sense to do it by hand. Normally it does not :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main () {
    int n=0;
    std::string cuvant;
    std::vector<std::string> lista_cuvinte;
    std::cout<<" Cate cuvinte doriti sa comparati = "<< std::endl;
    std::cin>> n;

    // read data 
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {   
        std::cout<<"cubantul al " << i + 1 <<" -lea = ";
        std::cin>> cuvant;
        lista_cuvinte.push_back(cuvant);
    }   

    // sort data 
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++) 
    {   
        for (int j=i + 1; j < n; j++) 
        {   
            if (lista_cuvinte.at(i) > lista_cuvinte.at(j)) 
            {   
                std::string temp=lista_cuvinte.at(i);
                lista_cuvinte[i]=lista_cuvinte.at(j);
                lista_cuvinte[j]=temp;
                i=i-1;
                break;
            }   
        }   
    }   

    // output data
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {   
        std::cout << lista_cuvinte[i] << std::endl;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

And with std::sort your code in the section sorting reduces to:

```
        // sort data 
    std::sort( lista_cuvinte.begin(), lista_cuvinte.end());
```

Thats all!

As a hint to you for writing and finding errors in general: Please use a debugger. Your code simply throws an exception. Your debugger will catch it for you and you go in the backtrace to the point where the error occurs. In your code it was an access out of range from the array, because the data was not read in at this point of execution.

Comment: And, for what it's worth (maybe educational purposes), the actual error came from using `n` instead of `lista_cuvinte.size()` and stepping over bounds on `at(i)` inside the sorting loops. Sorting at each input was "fine", even the terrible overshadowing of `i` was "ok". It's funny how it almost "worked".

Comment: when you put it like that it even looks easier :) thank you for the help, i understood know. This was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting sorting before completing the input of the words. Your second `for (int i=0...` loop is inside your first one.

Comment: I didn't reply cause i was trying to figure out how to arrange them, but Klaus was faster. Thank you for your help.